# Ошибки с кодировкой Python 3.x

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8

Всем привет. Решил написать парсер странички с одной таблицей на питоне. В "мета"-теге страницы указана кодировка utf-8. Я считываю все нужные мне данные из этой таблицы, но русские символы записываются непонятной абракадаброй. Вот код программки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8
import lxml.html as html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://org.mephi.ru/pupil-rating/get-rating/entity/4575/original/no')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
range_list = tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[1]/text()')
unique_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[3]/text()')
fio_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[4]/text()')
hostel_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[5]/text()')
score_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[6]/span[1]/text()')
sum_score_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[7]/text()')
docs_list=tree.xpath('//tr[@class="trPosBen"]/td[8]/text()')
```

Затем все эти списки я объединяю в 'result_list', чтобы получилась таблица.
При выводе в консоль все срабатывает без ошибок, но русские символы выводятся следующим образом: ÐÐÐ¯Ð£ ÐÐÐ¤Ð. При попытке записать эту "таблицу" в текстовый файл выскакивает ошибка кодировки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vasiiil/PycharmProjects/untitled/HelloWorld.py", line 55, in <module>
  f.write(str(i[j]) + " ")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>
```

После того, как добавил параметр 'encoding='utf-8' в файловую переменную ошибка не выскакивает. Но в файл записывается все та же абракадабра: ÐÐÐ¯Ð£ ÐÐÐ¤Ð.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже третий день лажу по интернету в поисках решения данной проблемы, но так ничего и не нашел.

Comment: `lxml` иногда мог иметь проблемы с Юникодом. [Можно `beautifulsoup4` пакет использовать, чтобы автоматически правильную кодировку подбирать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15302125/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй

```
html.fromstring(page.raw.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

или

```
page.encoding = 'utf-8'
html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Теперь все корректно отображается

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = 'texqweфывыфвt'.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
>>> print(a)
texqweфывыфвt
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Все те же символы на выходе. При задании значения переменной в коде или считывании из текстового файла русские символы нормально распознаются без дополнительного кодирования и декодирования. С это проблемой я столкнулся именно при считывании html страницы